# hibernate h2 embeddable list expected "identifier"

Tags: java, hibernate, h2, embeddable

I'm trying to associate a list of function (whom Embeddable) within my Employee Entity and H2 seems unhappy with this saying that it expected an "identifier"

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "
>       CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE_FUNCTIONS (
>           EMPLOYEE_EMPLOYEEID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
>           ACTIVE BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
>           DEPARTMENTNUMBER INTEGER NOT NULL,
>           DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(255),
>           ORDER[*] INTEGER NOT NULL
>       ) "; expected "identifier";

The thing is I already done that with an other project and I don't see why it doesn't work.

Employee.java

```
@Entity
public class Employee extends AbstractScheduleEntity<EmployeeSchedule> {
    public static final String ACOMBA_UNIQUE_FIELD = "acombaUnique";

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "sequence_id", strategy = 
    "ca.tecsar.core.sql.ServerSequenceGenerator")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "sequence_id")
    @Column(name = "EmployeeID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String employeeID;
    @ElementCollection
    private List<Function> functions;

    //getter and setter
}
```

Function.java

```
@Embeddable
public class Function implements Serializable {
    private int order;
    private boolean active;
    private String description;
    private int departmentNumber;

    //getter and setter
}
```

I removed a few properties in Employee that wasn't necessary.
What may cause this error? Is it because I have a String as identifier in my Employee? If so how can I tell to Hibernate to add Employee_EmployeeID as identifier?
Thanks

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Turns out I was being dumb and named a column "Order". Wonder why H2 wasn't happy :upside_down:

Changed the variable name to something else and it worked!

Comment: `ORDER` is a reserved keyword for H2DB - http://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#compatibility

Comment: Yes I understood that.

Comment: ```@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL) private RaceGroup group``` ```GROUP```also causes same problem. :P

Comment: I also run into this problem but in my case reserved word was `offset`. Renaming column helped.

Comment: had same issue, in my case its the "from" field that is causing problem so I have to specify @Column(name = "from_date") to avoid conflict with reserved words.

Comment: having a column named "value" will produce the same error, because its reserved as well

Answer (score 9):

I have the same problem while naming the fields: `private String to` and `private String from` , changed to ex. dayTo , dayFrom , and it worked.

Comment: Exactly my case, I had `from` and `until` dates, that broke my query. Renaming them to `fromDate` and `untilDate` solved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Got same issue with Order as entity. Changed table name to "orderz" and goes on.

Comment: THIS! Took me one hour to figure out.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Spring and H2 database for tests, My entity had the field name **"interval"**, I renamed to **"inter"** and resolved the problem.

So, these errors happen due to a sql reserved names in entities.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing a similar issue because of a field in my entity called "interval".
The answers to this post help me identify the root cause, however changing the name of the field was not a solution for me because "interval" was perfect for my class.

The solution I used was to rename the table column by using hibernate annotation.

```
 @Column(name = "FREQUENCY_INTERVAL")
 private int interval;
```

This helped me keep the variable name as 'interval' while mapping to a column name that is acceptable by the database.

Answer (score 1):

I also had an issue with an entity field called `row` as it is also a keyword

I specified a Column name (`"SEAT_ROW"`) to get around it.

```kotlin
@Entity
data class Seat (
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    val id :            Long,
    @Column(name="SEAT_ROW")
    val row :           Char,
    val num :           Int,
    val price :         BigDecimal,
    val description :   String
) {
    override fun toString(): String = "Seat $row-$num $$price ($description)"
}
```

[H2 Compatibility and Keywords Table](http://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#compatibility)

Answer (score 1):

I was using order as table name in h2. Changed to something like _order and I get it!

As you can see [here](http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html), order is a reserved word by h2.

Answer (score 0):

try to put the  ; before the " and test ?

Comment: The query is generated by Hibernate not me

Answer (score 0):

in my case problem cause was incorrect syntax in insert statement
problem :

```
insert into 'table name missing' (column names...) values(values...);
```

after adding table name

fix:

```
insert into 'table name specified' (column names...) values(values...);
```

some times trivial mistakes are hard to spot :)

Answer (score 0):

For your script will be compatible with reserved words,
it would be: "ORDER", see here:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE_FUNCTIONS ( EMPLOYEE_EMPLOYEEID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, ACTIVE BOOLEAN NOT NULL, DEPARTMENTNUMBER INTEGER NOT NULL, DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(255), "ORDER" INTEGER NOT NULL );
```

using the tip reserved words by albertocavalcante user.

Answer (score 0):

Double check all your column names in your entity.
Be sure you are not using reserved keywords, and if you are, add an alias using:

```
@Column(name = "<YOUR NOT RESERVED KEYWORD COLUMN NAME>")
```

To the Entity attribute you are suspecting may be a reserved keyword, i.e.

```
@Column(name = "_user")
private String user
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but, how can I do if the column comes from a Oracle DB, so I can't change the name? I use H2 only for local testing purpose, and connect to Oracle DB in production env.

Comment: In my case I use: jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=Oracle;NON_KEYWORDS=VALUE

Comment: I think `order` attribute from your `Function` class is an Oracle Reserved Word, double check that here in the Oracle official docs. <https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a42525/apb.htm> If that is the case, consider an alias for that `order` column, or refactor to a different name. i.e. `employee_order`

Answer (score -1):

I had the somewhat same problem but instead mine was missing a semi-colon.

Comment: This seem more like a comment than an answer. Can you provide an example with some code?